# If statements only execute corresponding print statement when all three have been run

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am having trouble explaining the following behaviour.

Can someone please explain to me why, when I run the following program the user can input three incorrect answers and the print statement that should read 'Incorrect' is not printed until the end of the loop?

```
def main():

UserName = input ('What is your name?')
UserAge = input ('What is your age?')


sum1 = input ('What is 3 x 3?')
sum2 = input ('What is 1 + 7?')
sum3 = input ('What is 9 - 8?')


if sum1 =='9':
    print('Correct1')

else:
    print ('Incorrect1')

if sum2 =='8':
    print('Correct2')
else:
    print ('Incorrect2')

if sum3 =='1':
    print('Correct3')
else:
    print ('Incorrect3')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: No response - tagging as `python` for now...

Comment: It's python3 probably because of the print statement

Comment: There is no loop... (or free lunch). Also, that Python code is not correctly indented, so it won't even run, and there are several different possible ways it could be indented that would mean entirely different things. Fix the code so it correctly reflects what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

I have answered this based on your question reading to me, as: "Why does the console not print incorrect/correct until the end of the program?"

The answer to which is: This is how you defined the program. ie)You asked for input on the second question before you replied to the first.

See below fix:

```
def main():

 UserName = input ('What is your name?')
 UserAge = input ('What is your age?')


sum1 = input ('What is 3 x 3?')

if sum1 =='9':
print('Correct1')

else:
print ('Incorrect1')

sum2 = input ('What is 1 + 7?')

if sum2 =='8':
print('Correct2')
else:
print ('Incorrect2')

sum3 = input ('What is 9 - 8?')
if sum3 =='1':
print('Correct3')
else:
print ('Incorrect3')

if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
```

Comment: I should also note you have not added what language this is, so I am unable to correct any syntax errors.